# Comparing object ids of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have been using `numpy` for quite a while but I stumbled upon one thing that I didn't understand fully:

```
a = np.ones(20)
b = np.zeros(10)

print(id(a)==id(b))          # prints False
print(id(a), id(b))          # prints (4591424976, 4590843504)

print(id(a[0])==id(b[0]))    # prints True 
print(id(a[0]), id(b[0]))    # prints (4588947064, 4588947064)

print(id(a[0]))              # 4588947184
print(id(b[0]))              # 4588947280
```

Can someone please explain the behavior observed in last four print statements? Also, I was aware of the fact that `id` gives you unique object id actually allocated in the memory but every time I run the last two print statements, I got different `id` values. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: The `id(a[0])` doesn't tell you anything useful.  `a` is not a list, nor is it an object dtype array.  `a[0]` is a value, not a unique object in the array.  Or to put it another way, each time you do this `[0]` indexing, `numpy` makes a **new** `np.float` object that contains the value.

Comment: @Chris, wrong duplicate.  This isn't about the `id` of Python integers and/or floats.  It's about 'unboxing' of `numpy` array elements.

Comment: @Chris I think this one is totally different

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that you should forget about relying on `id` to try and gain deep insight into the workings of python. Its output is affected by CPython implementation details, peephole optimizations and memory reuse. More often than not `id` is a red herring. This is especially true with numpy.

In your specific case only `a` and `b` exist as python objects. When you take an element, `a[0]`, you instantiate a new python object, a scalar of type `numpy.float64`. These are new python objects and are thus given a new `id`, *unless* the interpreter realizes that you're trying to use this object twice (this is probably what's happening in your middle example, although I do find it surprising that two `numpy.float64` objects with different values are given the same `id`. But the weird magic goes away if you assign `a[0]` and `b[0]` to proper names first, so this is probably due to some optimization). It could also happen that memory addresses get reused by the interpreter, giving you `id`s that have appeared before.

Just to see how pointless `id` is with numpy, even trivial views are new python objects with new `id`s, even though for all intents and purposes they are as good as the original:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(3)

>>> id(arr)
140649669302992

>>> id(arr[...])
140649669667056
```

And here's an example for `id` reuse in an interactive shell:

```
>>> id(np.arange(3))
139775926634896

>>> id(np.arange(3))
139775926672480

>>> id(np.arange(3))
139775926634896
```

Surely there's no such thing as [`int` interning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/5067311) for numpy arrays, so the above is only due to the interpreter reusing `id`s. The fact that `id` returns a memory address is again just a CPython implementation detail. Forget about `id`.

The only thing you might want to use with numpy is [`numpy.may_share_memory`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html) and [`numpy.shares_memory`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html#numpy.shares_memory).

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that everything in Python is an object, even numbers and Classes.
You have taken 2 numpy array object and each of contains same values i.e 0. 
When you say:

```
print('id of 0 =',id(0))

a = 0
print('id of a =',id(a))

b = a
print('id of b =',id(b))

c = 0.0
print('id of c =',id(c))
```

The answer you get something like (your case it's different):

```
id of 0 = 140472391630016
id of a = 140472391630016
id of b = 140472391630016
id of c = 140472372786520
```

Hence, integer `0` has a unique id. The id of the integer `0` remains constant during the lifetime. Similar is the case for float `0.0` and other objects.
So in your case `a[0]` or `b[0]` object id of zero will remain same until or unless it is alive because both contains `0` as object value.
Each time you print `a[0]` or `b[0]` in different line you return it's different identity of object because you triggering it at different line hence different lifetime.
You can try:

```
print(id(a)==id(b))
print(id(a),id(b))
print(id(a[0])==id(b[0]))
print(id(a[0]),id(b[0]))
```

The output will be:

```
False
2566443478752 2566448028528
True
2566447961120 2566447961120
```

Note that second line will return to you 2 different identity of object of numpy array type because both are different list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. "_The id of the integer 0 remains constant during the lifetime_": this is true, but in `a[0]` the lifetime of that "`0`" is only constrained to that indexing expression. The fact that you get the same `0` object in `a[0], b[0]` is a cpython implementation detail. It would no longer be true with `a[1000], b[1000]`, but I don't think this would affect the behaviour the OP is asking about.

Comment: Hi Andras, I had found some details on ID from source https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/id 
I had given my points just to explain the ID remain same for object in their lifetime. I miss and wasn't give mention the answer from cpython perspective.